# The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application visual studio code

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Somebody please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh4Kc.png)

can't create flutter project,can't run flutter doctor in visual code.look picture "The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application."

Comment: Please follow official guidelines I do not think you have your environment variables set

Answer (score 0):

please check your definitions in environment variables.
.net 3.5 framework path or other variable path may not be defined.